# [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in watcher with expression "chartData"

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

Below is a copy of my vue file with the watcher mentioned in the warning:

```
<script>
  import { Radar } from 'vue-chartjs'

  export default {
    extends: Radar,
    props:['chartData','options'],
    mounted () {
      this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
    },
    watch: {
      chartData: {
        handler: function(newVal, oldVal) {
          this.$data._chart.update()
        },
        deep: true
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I don't see anything wrong with the code and don't know why it is causing a loop. Any help would be appreciated. I am passing in chartData via props. If you need anything else, please let me know.

To try to make things easier, below is how I am passing in the prop chartData:

```
<caChampions :chartData="dataForLChampions" :options="optionsForLChampions" />
```

This data is updated every time someone selects something from a drop-down. The code from the drop-down is below:

```
<v-autocomplete
                label="Champion"
                placeholder="Enter Champion's Name Here"
                :loading="championSelectLoading"
                v-model="selectedChampion"
                @input="getChampionInfo()"
                :items="champions"
                autocomplete
                autofocus
                outline
                full-width
                ></v-autocomplete>
```

The first time someone selects something, it works great. However, the second selection on creates a loop and I am not sure why.

Comment: Maybe you should just call renderChart from the watcher instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `reactiveProp` mixin instead of update chart yourself.

In [document](https://vue-chartjs.org/#/home?id=reactive-data), it said:

> On data change, it will either call update() if only the data inside
>   the datasets has changed or renderChart() if new datasets were added.

```
<script>
  import { Radar, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'

  export default {
    extends: Radar,
    props:['chartData','options'],
    mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp],
    mounted () {
      this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have put you down as the answer, although I had to find a different workaround. For some reason, using the mixin wasn't catching the updates to the data (the mixin watches chartData for updates). However, the answer at the bottom of a github issue for vue-chartjs (url below) worked for me.

https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/44

Comment: @TytonDon yeah that's because the reactiveProp mixin does not have `deep: true` so it doesn't catch those changes

Answer (score 0):

ChartJS mutates the data object every time you invoke `update()` or upon the first-time render. It adds `_meta` property to `chartData.dataset` and because you use a `deep` watcher, Vue invokes the watcher immediately after ChartJS adding/updating `_meta` causing an infinite update loop.

The solution, as @ittus has pointed out, is to use the builtin mixin that comes along with the package. It has a limit that you must replace the entire `chartData` object to be reactive. Otherwise, you have to invoke `update()` manually after the data object is changed, because internally, the watcher provided by the mixin is not `deep`.

However, if you are not using `vue-chartjs` library and have built your own wrapper, or you insist to use a `deep` watcher, you can make a deep clone of the `data` object. You can either use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` or [`cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) from Lodash.

Further reads:

- https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/issues/250
- https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/611#issuecomment-613886129